# How to keep "Reference" heading in uppercase with natbib package

Tags: bibtex, acm

I'm writing a paper, which follows ACM style in latex. The document class I used is `\documentclass{sig-alternate}`.

My problem is that when I use `natbib` package to make the references and citation in sequence, reference heading becomes in lower case and also removes the serial number of the reference section. Note ACM uses a serial number for this section.
I have also used other packages for other works. The used packages are as follows:

```
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage[nocompress]{cite}
 \usepackage{cite}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage[noend]{algpseudocode}
\usepackage{verbatimbox}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{scalerel}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{fixltx2e}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{fancyvrb}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{epstopdf}
\usepackage{threeparttable}
\usepackage[numbers,sort&compress]{natbib}
\usepackage{hyphenat}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\captionsetup{compatibility=false}
```

I am using sigproc file as `BibTex` database for the reference list, and used the following commands:

```
\bibliographystyle{unsrtnat} 
\bibliography{sigproc}
```

The reference section is look like: "Reference", instead of "9. REFERENCE".
Please help!
Thanks.

Comment: Since you want to use the `natbib` package, don't also load the `cite` package (twice!).

Answer (score 1):

According  to the `natbib` manual one has to redefine `\bibsection`, thus your can achieve what you want with

```
\renewcommand{\bibsection}{\section{REFERENCES}}
```